# boost face detection/recognition process in python (opencv + tensorflow +CNN)

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, tensorflow, computer-vision

I am working on a face detection and recognition app in python using tensorflow and opencv. The overall flow is as follow:

```
while True:

        #1) read one frame using opencv: ret, frame = video_capture.read()

        #2) Detect faces in the current frame using tensorflow (using mxnet_mtcnn_face_detection)

        #3) for each detected face in the current frame, run facenet algorithm (tensorflow) and compare with my Database, to find the name of the detected face/person

        #4) displlay a box around each face with the name of the person using opencv
```

Now, my issue is that the overhead (runtime) of face detection and recognition is very high and thus sometime the output video is more like a slow motion! I tried to use tracking methods (e.g., MIL, KCF), but in this case, I cannot detect new faces coming into the frame! Any approach to increase the speedup? At least to get rid of "face recognition function" for those faces that already recognized in previous frames!

Comment: what is the size of your image ? and what machine are you running this on?

Comment: Frame size (from camera): (480, 640, 3). I use standard facenet model which is already trained (160, 160, 3). Windows 10. i7 6600U 2.8 HGz, Ram: 16GB. No GPU.

Comment: Get a GPU. Even a cheap one (like 1050Ti at $150ish) should get the job done better than a fast CPU when it come to AI. If you are on a budget, remember to get more VRAM over clock speed.